# Regex pattern not matching

Tags: regex

I have a pattern which should follow:

```
some-name:word1,some-name2:word2,some-name3:word3
```

It starts with a word (ie-apple), followed by a colon (`:`) and afterwards it should be either (`word1` or `word2` or `word3`) and there shouldn't be any comma at EOL. (apple:word1)

I am using pattern as below:

```
((.*?):(word1|word2|word3),){1,}((.*?):(word1|word2|word3))$
```

But it fails if i put a word as below:

```
some-word:word1,some-word:word2,failed_word,some_wordx:word3
```

Here in above example (failed_word) didn't follow the pattern and it should fail but its passing through.

Can someone please suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Try `^\w+-\w+:(?:word1|word2|word3)(?:,\w+-\w+:(?:word1|word2|word3))*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkCRwy/1)

Comment: What is your definition of *"It starts with a word (ie-apple)"*? Why didn't `failed_word` follow the pattern? Can the first word only consist of letters and hyphens (`-`)? Is the hyphen required? Are underscores not allowed as part of the word? i.e. would `ie-failed_word` be valid as first word?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works with your first example and fails with your second example:

```
^([^:,]+\:(word1|word2|word3))(,[^:,]+\:(word1|word2|word3))+$
```